# nls modelling code doesn't work with a lag variable in the formula

Tags: r

I'm trying to use an equation with a lag and carryover effect function. Here are two codes to give an example. The first code test1 runs ok.

```
library(stats)
library(dplyr)
df<- mtcars
test1 <- nls( mpg ~ base 
             + a1*disp 
             + a2*wt
             + a3*hp        
             , 
             data=df , 
             start=c(base=20, a1=1, a2=1, a3=1), 
             algorithm="port", 
             na.action = "na.exclude" )
```

This code doesn't run, after I introduce the lag function where the a3 and a4 coefficients

```
test2 <- nls( mpg ~ base 
             + a1*disp 
             + a2*wt
             + a3*(hp + a4*dplyr::lag(hp) )         
             , 
             data=df, 
             start=c(base=20, a1=1, a2=1, a3=1 , a4=1), 
             algorithm="port", 
             na.action = "na.exclude" )
```

I know that the lag creates an NA in the first observation, so I've tried using data = df[-1,] but that doesn't work. So assume it does the subsetting before the model is calculated. Is there a way I can change this code to get it to run? Any help greatly appreciated. Thanks

Edit: it would be great if the lag is specified in the formula, than a workaround.

Answer (score 2):

How about this:
I just created the lag variable before fitting the model.

```
library(stats)
library(dplyr)
df<- mtcars
df$lag_hp=dplyr::lag(df$hp)
test2 <- nls( mpg ~ base 
              + a1*disp 
              + a2*wt
              + a3*(hp + a4*lag_hp )         
              , 
              data=df, 
              start=c(base=20, a1=1, a2=1, a3=1 , a4=1), 
              algorithm="port", 
              na.action = "na.exclude" )
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I was hoping to be able to adjust the lag in formula so I can test multiple lags manually for any variable, without creating multiple variables. However, I can work with this. Many thanks